# Нечастая факультативность двоеточия и тире при цитировании: на что ориентироваться?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, прямая-речь, двоеточие, цитата

Обратил внимание на вопрос на портале "Грамота.ру" (см. [здесь](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=309625)). Почему в данном случае можно не ставить двоеточие перед цитатой (ну или перед несколькими подряд идущими цитатами) и после неё также не ставить никаких знаков препинания? Скажем, интонационное тире ведь можно поставить, чтобы показать, что длинная цитата закончилась и продолжается предложение, или это излишне?

**Вопрос:** Скажите, правильно ли оформлено предложение? *От этих его фраз а-ля "Кто бы говорил, я же служил, я лучше знаю!" кругом голова.*

**Ответ:** Если это три разные фразы, лучше оформить так: *От этих его фраз а-ля «Кто бы говорил!», «Я же служил!», «Я лучше знаю!» кругом голова.*

**То есть можно и так?**

*От этих его фраз а-ля(:) «Кто бы говорил!», «Я же служил!», «Я лучше знаю!» (—) кругом голова.*

*От этих его фраз а-ля(:) «Кто бы говорил, я же служил, я лучше знаю!» (—) кругом голова.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово *а-ля* означает "подобно", "похоже", "типа".

1. Фраза или фразы после *а-ля* в кавычках — это не цитаты, а примеры, поэтому двоеточие не нужно.
2. *А-ля* — предлог, не является обобщающим словом, поэтому двоеточие после него не нужно.

Итак, двоеточие ни в каком случае не требуется.

Comment: Ладно, а если бы "а-ля" не было, могла бы быть пара двоеточия и тире?

Comment: @ShiKomarishe могла бы быть.

Comment: Хорошо, но двоеточие всё равно возможно ведь теоретически? "Грамота.ру" вон любит после "вроде" (а это синоним "а-ля") перед цитатой его ставить. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=309604

Comment: @ShiKomarishe нет, не может. Смысловая синонимичность не означает пунктуационной. К примеру, зависимые слова, присоединяемые с помощью "вроде", согласуются с глпвными: "город вроде Москвы", "напиток вроде сидра", а присоединяемые с помощью "а-ля" — не согласуются: "город а-ля Москва", "напиток а-ля сидр".